# Share by using DataTransferManager makes the app crash/restart on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm using DataTransferManager API to trigger sharing on Windows 10 Mobile.

After having called DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI() everything goes fine if I proceed quite quickly either by cancelling or completing the sharing (via outlook, facebook or any other).

But if I wait for 15-20 seconds doing nothing while the Share UI is displayed, when I'm going back to my app, my app is killed and restarted.

I think there is something bad inside DataTransferManager API

Is there any workaround ?

```
private void Share_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
            DataTransferManager dtManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
            dtManager.DataRequested += dtManager_DataRequested;
        }

        private void dtManager_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int sharingIndex = pivot.SelectedIndex;
                e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "Shared From test App";
                e.Request.Data.SetText("\nYou have been shared with an article from test Application");
                e.Request.Data.SetApplicationLink(new Uri("TestURL"));
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just tested with the official [Sharing content target app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/482f390715fc48b0c51cba2b8c664b6d65ed9129/Samples/ShareTarget) and [Sharing content source app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/482f390715fc48b0c51cba2b8c664b6d65ed9129/Samples/ShareSource) on mobile emulator with OS build 14393 over 10 times, I can't reproduce your issue, each time I waited for over one minute. Could you please show some code or tell us your OS build?

Comment: Hi grace, i am using windows 10 mobile and testing in device. I am facing the same issue even in MSN official news app.

Comment: I have added code which i have been using, please look into it.

Comment: What is your OS version?

Comment: OS Version: 1607, OS build: 10.0.14393.67